# JSON format and rerun a line?

Tags: python, json

I'm a newbie, sorry for the silly question.

I use a python notebooks JSON format.
In a line I open the file:

```
f=open(namefile)
```

in another one I create a dictionary:

```
fips=dict()
for row in f:
    bla bla bla
```

If I run the first one and then the second one everything is ok and the dictionary is created correctly but if I try to rerun the second group of lines the dictionary will be empty. Why?

Comment: after you read all the rows in `f` f is then empty and has no rows. When you run the second part again you create a new empty dict, then this time there are no more lines left in `f` which is why you have an empty dict

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in f:
```

This line of codes runs a loop through every line in the file, but it is basically a generator, which means it only runs once. Running another loop will always fail:

```
for row in f:
    print('in the loop')
# Nothing is printed
```

The correct way to do it is to first save all the lines to another variable:

```
f=open(namefile)
lines = f.readlines()
```

Then you can iterate over it multiple times:

```
fips=dict()
for row in lines:
    print('in first loop')

for row in lines:
    print('in second loop')
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a pretty strange behaviour for me. At first look the two for seem the same thing with the exception that you have copied the lines in another variables.